# Matching Word/ Text

Tags: vb.net

normally i use element from webbrowser to add strings or tags from the webbrowser. This time i am using webclient to download the document text, as seen;

Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("hats,com")

So basically i download the document of a website, now this document has a bunch of websites starting with the same word, in this case > https, seen below.

"x" "https://hats.com/xxx", "x"

so im trying to get all the words (in this case links) that start with (https://hats.com/xxx) and add them to a listbox.

so first index will be the first match/ word that starts with the url, second index will be the second url found with same start.

Comment: Show us some code...

Comment: i can download webclient to textbox, from there i dont know what to do, its why im asking. I can get first word search by .startswith or .contains but i dont know for getting "all" that start with the same string into a listbox, from first string match = first index. 2nd matching string =2nd index.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack (available from Nuget) may be useful for you to navigate HTML code in ways alike (not identical, though) you'd do with Webbrowser control

Comment: i dont want to get into other stuff really, just want to keep it simple with the text i have downloaded since its most easiest to do, just getting the words (links) that contain the start of the https, ill look into htmlagility anyway however incase its simpler, helps. Thanks

Comment: IMHO it's silly to not use the right tool to do the job ; but if you want to stick that way ; you could `String.IndexOf` in combination with `String.Substring` if you have a reliable way to determine the end of a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know understand exactly what you mean but maybe this will work (Try which one works best for you) I think you want the second one.

```
Dim str1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    str1 = str1.Replace(",", "")
    str1 = str1.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim str2 As String() = str1.Split({""""}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim str3 As String = str2(0)
    For Each i In str2
        If i.StartsWith(str3) Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
```

Or

```
Dim str1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    str1 = str1.Replace(",", "")
    str1 = str1.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim str2 As String() = str1.Split({""""}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each i In str2
        If i.StartsWith("https") Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
```

Replace `TextBox1` with your textbox name and `ListBox1` with your listbox name.

If neither of these work for you please explain better what you want and add some code you have tried.

Comment: SECOND ONE< THANKYOU!! Feel so thankful rn, worked very similar how i imagined, i was just lost because i didnt know if it would add all items, thankyou very very much